# Can't get my cards to flip with Vanilla JS, CSS and HTML using CSS animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, addeventlistener

I'm trying to make a simple flashcard app using the examples you see in a lot of the codepens on line. I'm bringing in a database of card data from Rails and want to render all the cards on a page for flipping.

Right now I can get all the cards to load with the data but they don't flip. I think there's something wrong with the way I'm trying to add all the cards to a 'click' eventListener using `querySelectorAll` and `classItems.toggle`.

Here's the code:

HTML

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css" /> -->

  <title>CrashCard</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1 style="text-align: center">Crash Card</h1>
  </header>

  <form class="ui form" id="form">
    <div class="field">
      <label>Card Front</label>
      <input type="text" name="card-front" placeholder="Card Front" id="card-front" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label>Card Back</label>
      <input type="text" name="card-back" placeholder="Card Back" id="card-back" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
    </div>
    </div>
    <button class="ui button" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>

  <div class="container" id="card-container">

  </div>



  </body>
  <script src="src/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body { font-family: sans-serif; }

.scene {
  width: 200px;
  height: 260px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  margin: 40px 0;
  perspective: 600px;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: center right;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.card.is-flipped {
  transform: translateX(-100%) rotateY(-180deg);
}

.card__face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 260px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card__face--front {
  background: black;
}

.card__face--back {
  background: rgb(227, 230, 236);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Javascript:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    console.log("DOM is loaded");


    let allFlashcards = [];
    let cardToggle = false

        const form = document.getElementById('form')
        const cardContainer = document.getElementById('card-container')



    // fetch all cards

    const fetchCards = () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:9000/api/v1/flashcards')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(flashcards => {
                allFlashcards = flashcards
                getFlashcards()
            });
    }


    // flip action 

    const getFlashcards = () => {
        return allFlashcards.map(c => {
            return cardContainer.innerHTML += `
            <div class="scene scene--card">
             <div class="card">
                <div class="card__face card__face--front">${c.body_front}</div>
                <div class="card__face card__face--back">${c.body_back}</div>
             </div>
            </div>
            <br />   
            `
        })
    };

    // listen for card click

    const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
        cards.forEach(c => c.addEventListener("click",  () => c.classList.toggle('is-flipped')))


    // create new card form 

    form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const cardFront = document.getElementById('card-front').value
        const cardBack = document.getElementById('card-back').value
        fetch('http://localhost:9000/api/v1/flashcards', {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                body_front: cardFront,
                body_back: cardBack
            })
        }).then(res => res.json())
            .then(newCard => {
                allFlashcards.push(newCard)

            })
    });

    fetchCards()

}); // end DOMContentLoaded
```

I need the cards to flip one at a time. Do I need to do a comparison with a dataset? Or will this CSS animation be enough to know which card is clicked.

Comment: For starters, try to use the debugger to check if you reach the "toggle class" code on click event. Put a break point and click the element.

Comment: Yes I am able to reach it. It's just not triggering the css `is-flipped`

Comment: Check that `c` is the object you want (the element) and check if the class is being added to the DOM. if not, you're probably not using the 'toggle' function right. (I'm not using this so I don't really know). If it doesn't but the view doesn't change, use the debugger to see what are the styles of the element, and why they are not derived from your class. This has not simple answer. You'll have to debug.

Comment: Yes will do. I thought that `this` might work but when debugging, `this` remains undefined and does not bind to the click action.

Comment: the value of "this" is dependent of context. Where in the code do you expect "this" to have a value?